# Reflection of two graphs on the same plane

Tags: python, sample

I have a population:

```
population_men  = stats.norm.rvs(loc=19, scale=171, size=11000000)  # Sample of men with an average height of 171
population_women = stats.norm.rvs(loc=16, scale=165, size=12000)  # A sample of women with an average height of 165

t, p = stats.ttest_ind(population_men, population_women)
t, p
result: (-0.1213798367777649, 0.9033901889229905)
```

Then I build a graph

```
plt.hist(population_men, bins=25, color = 'purple'); # Sample A
plt.hist(population_women, bins=25, color = 'blue');  # Sample B
```

Result:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAVTc.png)
I need to make both samples visible on the graph, as if layered on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `alpha` param to `plt.hist()`

Try:

```
plt.hist(population_men, bins=25, color = 'purple', alpha=0.5, density=True);
plt.hist(population_women, bins=25, color = 'blue', alpha=0.5, density=True);
```

The `size` in your `stats.norm.rvs()` is vastly different so you will only see the stats for `population_men`. You can fix this by making the 'size' in both variables similar or by using `density=True` to the normalize them.

Comment: Unfortunately it also shows 1 data group